# React-Native Refs are Undefined

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm currently working on an app and here is the essential code relevant to my bug:

Here is the render function:

```
render() {
 return (
  <ScrollableTabView>
    <NavigatorIOS
      translucent={false}
      initialRoute={{
        component: MenuList,
        title: '',
        passProps: { hideNavBar: this.hideNavBar,
                     showNavBar: this.showNavBar,
                     toggleFav: this.toggleFav,
                     getFavImg: this.getFavImg,
                    },
      }}
      navigationBarHidden={this.state.hideNavBar}
      style={{ flex: 1 }}
      barTintColor="#1f3157"
      titleTextColor="#f6f6f6"
      tabLabel="Menu"
    />
    <NavigatorIOS
      ref="nav"
      translucent={false}
      initialRoute={{
        component: FavoritesList,
        title: '',
        passProps: { hideNavBar: this.hideNavBar,
                     showNavBar: this.showNavBar,
                     favs: this.state.favs,
                   },
      }}
      navigationBarHidden={this.state.hideNavBar}
      style={{ flex: 1 }}
      barTintColor="#1f3157"
      titleTextColor="#f6f6f6"
      tabLabel="Favorites"
    />
    <SpecialsList tabLabel="Specials" />
  </ScrollableTabView>
);
```

So right now, I'm trying to make the second NavigatorIOS update when the user updates something in the first NavigatorIOS. I currently have it so when something gets updated in the first one, it calls a function, which then in turns calls a function to replace the second one:

```
toggleFav = ( item ) => {
 //if not a favorite / not in map
 if ( !this.state.favs[item.title] ){
  this.state.favs[item.title] = item;
  this.state.favs[item.title].faved = true;
 }
 else if ( this.state.favs[item.title].faved ){
  this.state.favs[item.title].faved = false;
 }
 else {
  this.state.favs[item.title].faved = true;
 }

 this.favChange();
}

favChange = () => {
 this.refs.nav.replace({
        component: FavoritesList,
        title: '',
        passProps: {
              hideNavBar: this.hideNavBar,
              showNavBar: this.showNavBar,
              favs: this.state.favs,
        },
      });
}
```

The error i'm getting right now is that the `this.refs.nav` is undefined in the `favChange` function. I know it must be an issue with the `this`, but I don't have the faintest idea how to fix it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Haven't looked into the details, have you tried `toggleFav: this.toggleFav.bind(this)` instead of just `toggleFav: this.toggleFav` since you said there must be an issue with `this`?

Comment: (Does React Native have different rules about directly modifying state? E.g., `this.state.favs[item.title] = item` would be a no-no in regular-React-land; anything that directly modifies state, which `toggleFav` does all over, isn't ok.)

Comment: @DaveNewton In almost every case that shouldn't be done (it's React after all), but sometimes it can be fine as long as you trigger an update via `.setState(this.state)` or other equivalent methods.

Comment: Try passing the ref as a property, `secNav={this.refs.nav}` to the first navigator then you should be able to just do `this.props.secNav...`

Answer (score 0):

It might be because of "this" binding.
this.favChange = this.favChange.bind(this)
Can you try adding this code in your constructor or initialization code.

Comment: `favChange` is an arrow function and should be bound automatically. In any case, asking a poster to try something is better expressed as a comment.